# The dot operator and Numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am writing some code to solve some math problems, but I am having a little trouble understanding how to implement linear algebra operations with Numpy.

I thought `b = np.array([4, 5])` was supposed to represent a 1x2 matrix; but this not appear to be the case. If you have a matrix A, then if you do `A @ b` the array `b` behaves like a 2x1 matrix, while if you do `b @ A` then `b` behaves like a 1x2 matrix.

So, how should I think of `b`? Should I think of it as a flexible vector, meaning that it can be either a row vector or a column vector depending on what makes sense? Is this something people just get used to, or should I "hardcode" `b` as an actual 2x1 vector, as in `b = np.array([[4], [5]])`?

Are there any other "weird" behaviors of Numpy arrays? (meaning, you code some operations, but Numpy interprets it differently than you would think, from a math backgroung)

Comment: I think you should take a look at NumPy's docs on [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Also, you can add axes with `unsqueeze` or `np.newaxis`.

Comment: Your `b` has shape `[2]`, is a one-dimensional vector with two elements. The `@` operator simply calls [`np.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html), see the documentation of that function for an explanation of the behaviour with one-dimensional inputs.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product describes the **dot product** as returning a single number from two equal length sequences.  That's what `np.dot` does when given 2 1d arrays.  Both `np.dot` and `np.matmul` explicitly describe what they do when one or both arguments is 1d.

Comment: Strictlyspeaking `numpy` does not have "vectors".  'row vector' and 'column vector' can be used to describe arrays with shape (1,n) and (n,1), but that extra dimension usually isn't needed in `numpy`.  A numpy array can have 0, 1, 2 or more dimensions, so isn't limited to the conventions of linear algebra 'matrices'.

Comment: Thank you all I will do more reading into these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double brackets to have b act as a matrix.

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[4, 5]])
c = np.array([[2],[3]])
print(np.matmul(b,c))
print(np.matmul(c,b))
```

Output:

```
[[23]]

[[ 8 10]
 [12 15]]
```

Comment: Hmm I've considered this option. It is a good practice though? Would it slow down the program?

Comment: It shouldn't impact performance. You can always turn your array into a matrix using b.reshape(1,-1) when you need to use matrix operations.